# Apache Kafka can't store data in broker

Tags: apache-kafka, store, configure

I'm using kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1, zookeeper is the one in kafka's package. Configuration is One broker, one partition, no replication. First i test my code on my own machine, test is ok, producer and consumer all can work well, but when i deploy the kafka on the server(27.57.100.**), and my running code on a machine(27.57.101.*)，all the macheines in LAN, and can access one another. My code is the same as the sample on the kafka's site:

```
public class MyProducer {
private static Properties props = new Properties();
private static String topic = "test11";

static {
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
}

public void produceMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                topic, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
        System.out.println(i);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    producer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyProducer myProducer = new MyProducer();
    myProducer.produceMessage();
}
```

}

The problem is strange, there is no error message, and when i start the producer program the first time, the broker can create topic directory, but the .log file's size is always 0, and the output need 30-40 seconds to print every i's value; When i start the producer program second time, the output print the i's value normally, but the value does not stored.
    I can create topic, send message and consume message in shell. Firewall is closed.
    I need your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Change `props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");` to the host running the Kafka broker.

Comment: I'm sorry, i wrote wrong here,  actually the running code is 27.57.100.**:9092